# Date-fns parseISO returning wrong date

Tags: javascript, date, date-fns

Hello I am getting wrong dates from Date-fns.
I am formatting new Date() with date-fns format.

```
format(date, "yyyy-MM-dd")
```

So when I console.log, this happens

```
console.log("dateOfBirth ", dateOfBirth); //  1997-04-06
console.log("parsedDate ", parseISO(dateOfBirth));  // 1997-04-05T18:00:00.000Z
```

Why are the two dates different?
So what's happening here?

Comment: This is because of the return type of methods.
format() return "an string" 
parseISO() returns "the parsed date in the local time zone"

Comment: remove the comma(,)  in log and use + symbol you will see the difference clearly.

```console.log("parsedDate "+parseISO(dateOfBirth)); ```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is just a timezone issue, try to append "T00:00" when you create your date object, when you don't specifies the hours, it depends on which timezone user is. Probably you are in UTC - 6, right?
`const dateOfBirth = new Date("1997-04-06T00:00")`