# parseISO in date-fns showing the incorrect date

Tags: reactjs, iso, date-fns

I'm attempting to understand what exactly date-fns is doing when using parseISO() as it seems to be adding 2 hours to the time that I have saved in the database. The data is as follows:

ISO Date/Time saved in database: 2022-09-20T19:52:53.000Z

Using format(parseISO(2022-09-20T19:52:53.000Z), "HH:mm:ss") I get this: 21:52:53 hrs

Somewhere along the line 2 hours are being added and unsure as to the cause. A comment left by Monash Joshi in ([stackoverflow issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65077242/date-fns-parseiso-returning-wrong-date)) hints towards an explanation but not really a solution. Want I want to show is just the parsed date/time value as it is. Would it thus make sense to manipulate the string that I receive from the database myself?

Thanks in advance for your help! And let me know if you need any further information.

Answer (score 0):

Z is short for Zulu time, or UTC/GMT.  When parsing a time value ending in Z, it will be converted into a local time... so whatever your system's current UTC offset is, it will be added to the time value.
My guess is that the local system you ran your code on was in time zone +02:00 (including DST, if applicable), which would explain why it's adding two hours to the ISO date value.